# How do you change the name of a .ttf font

Tags: truetype

How do you change the name of the font embedded in the .ttf file? (It's for a device that's expecting a hard coded font name that I'd like to swap w/ another more readable openly licensed font).

I'd prefer a method which I can implement myself rather than installing a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TrueType is a pretty complex binary data format -- the kind that takes an entire book-length spec to describe. I've worked with it in the distant past.

There are specialized tools that can edit fonts, including metadata like names. I would not recommend trying to mess with the binary data in a font file without such a tool. There might be libraries available that you could call to manipulate TrueType data; if one existed, I would guess Python would be the most likely language to find it in, because there's a long correlation between font hackers and Python (Guido van Rossum's brother is a well-known typographer.)

Answer (score 1):

This may be only useful in very specific situations, but should you need to change a font's name to something else that is the exact same length, you can do so in a hex editor (e.g. [Okteta](https://apps.kde.org/en-gb/okteta/). Find all the instances of the name, and then edit them to be  the new name. I  found there were 2 copies of the name in each place - one that's normal, and another with 0x00 in between each letter.

The only evidence I have that this actually works is empirical with a sample size of 1.